# In csharp, I want the button to appear whenever I want and disappear whenever I want

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button, icsharpcode

I tried this way, but the button does not appear even though the items are larger than 0.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Without more code it is difficult to see why not.
It might be that you are expecting that snippet of code to fire, but it is not.  Where is that called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Not my downvote, but posting an image of technical information like code, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Answer (score 4):

It's not enough to set it to `false` if you don't want it to show. You also need to set it to `true` when you want to see it again. But you can write one line that does both:

```
btnRemoveToCart.Visible = (lbxCart.Items.Count > 0);
```

Now we also no longer need the `if()` check.

Answer (score 1):

Try add

```
else
{
    btnRemoveToCart.Visible = true;
}
```